# Does iterating $x \cdot \sin(\frac 1 x) + x$ near $0$ approach $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $f^1(x) := x\,\sin(\frac{1}{x})+x$ and define $f^N (x):= f(f^{N-1}(x))$ for $N\in \mathbb{Z},\ N>1$.  For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}{f^N(x)}=0?$

Clearly, for $x\geq\frac{1}{\pi}, f(x)\geq\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Wolfram Alpha gives

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{\pi}{x\sin(\frac{1}{x})+x-xdx}=-\frac{2+π^2-2πSi(π)}{4π}\approx-0.01858458$$
which is negative, so it should "on average" decrease.  Is this a valid heuristic?

Comment: The integral from $0$ to $1/(2\pi)$ is positive so, on that interval, you might expect the iteration to "on average" increase. Furthermore, in every neighborhood of zero, there is an open set of points $x$ such that $f(x)>x$.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, I shall assume for the sake of continuity that
$f(0)=0$.
The sequence can

- diverge to infinity; This happens precisely for $x>\frac1\pi$
- or converge to fixed point $x_\infty$ of $f$ (that is, $x_\infty=0$ or $x_\infty=\frac1{k\pi}$).
- or converge to a periodic  cycle, such as points where $f(f(x))=x$ but $f(x)\ne x$.
- or behave chaotically.

In particular, the second bullet point tells  us that there are points that do not converge to $0$ in every neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Are there any starting points for which the sequence converges other than those that eventually equal their limits?

Comment: Can it converge to 0?